# Как установить библиотеку svg-android-2?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

Я хочу работать с SVG форматом, нашел статью на хабре

```
https://goo.gl/ZWNzdM
```

В которой подробно объясняется как работать с этим форматом и все бы ничего, но как только начинаешь искать как установить svg-android-2 библиотеку, то ничего нет. Там есть только 2 ссылки на гуглокод в котором есть ссылка на гид и в нем есть 5 java файлов, я подумал, что это библиотека(опыта у меня в этом не много) и скачал из в проект, но оказалось не то и все равно вот этот код весь подсвечивается красным и не распознает ничего...

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.raw.filename);
Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Как мне установить эту библиотеку?

svg Файл не распознается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в гугловскую библиотеку поддержки [*support library 23.2*](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html) добавлен класс [`VectorDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html), возможно это поможет вам в вашей работе

Comment: а есть у вас какой нибудь пример как изображение в формате svg можно установить в imageview при помощи нее?

Comment: то, что написано синим в сообщении выше - кликабельно, под VectorDrawable ссылка на гугловский гайд с примерами.

Comment: Странно, но теперь когда я добавляю в проект файл svg сам файл не распознается(( Я прикрепил скриншот

Answer (score 4):

Разобрался)) Нужно было скачать файл по этой ссылке

```
http://goo.gl/DQzxg9
```

У меня лично Ubuntu поэтому мне пришлось распаковать архив, в нем лежал архив в нужном мне формате jar потом я его добавил себе в AndroidStudio в проект ,в папку libs после чего нажал правой кнопкой на добавленный архив и из перечня выбрал add as a library и все заработало